# web2py:Grid csv exports shows ids not values for reference fields

Tags: csv, grid, web2py

Table structure like -

```
db.define_table('parent',
   Field('name'),format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('children',
   Field('name'),
   Field('mother','reference parent'),
   Field('father','reference parent'))
db.children.mother.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.parent.id,'%(name)s')
db.children.father.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.parent.id,'%(name)s')
```

Controller :

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.children, orderby=[db.children.id],
                        csv=True, 
                        fields=[db.children.id, db.children.name, db.children.mother, db.children.father])

    return dict(grid=grid)
```

Here grid shows proper values i.e names of the mother and father from the parent table.
But when I try to export it via csv link - resulted excelsheet shows ids and not the names of mother and father.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The CSV download just gives you the raw database values without first applying each field's `represent` attribute. If you want the "represented" values of each field, you have two options. First, you can choose the TSV (tab-separated-values) download instead of CSV. Second, you can define a custom export class:

```
import cStringIO

class CSVExporter(object):
    file_ext = "csv"
    content_type = "text/csv"

    def __init__(self, rows):
        self.rows = rows

    def export(self):
        if self.rows:
            s = cStringIO.StringIO()
            self.rows.export_to_csv_file(s, represent=True)
            return s.getvalue()
        else:
            return ''

grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.mytable, exportclasses=dict(csv=(CSVExporter, 'CSV')))
```

The `exportclasses` argument is a dictionary of custom download types that can be used to override existing types or add new ones. Each item is a tuple including the exporter class and the label to be used for the download link in the UI.

We should probably add this as an option.